# remeshing in sculpt mode creates a mesh across the gap

Tags: armature, sculpting, remesh

I have a single mesh object to which I have assigned armature. Upon a remesh in sculpt mode, an additional mesh is created across the gap which I dont want. Is there some tolerance setting that needs adjusting. I dont know how to measure the distance across the affected gap. Thanks!

[image]